# Output of Informix clob or text on the browser screen with PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo, informix, clob

I'm getting a CLOB or a Informix type TEXT result (text) from a database query, but don't know how to output it.

```
$preparedStatement = $dbinformix->prepare($sql3);
$preparedStatement->bindColumn(4, $tmp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$preparedStatement->execute();
$result = $preparedStatement->fetchAll();
```

- An `echo $tmp` results in a Resource id #47.
- A `var_dump($tmp)` results in a resource(47) of type (stream).
- An `fpassthru($tmp)` leaves the display blank.
- If I try to use PDO::PARAM_STR as the third bind parameter, the display is still blank.

So I have no idea how to get the text, which is in the CLOB (it's a few KB, not MB).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Do this with the "fetch column" syntax of [`PDOStatement::fetchAll`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) instead:

```
$preparedStatement = $dbinformix->prepare($sql3);
$preparedStatement->execute();

$tmp = $preparedStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 4);
```

`$tmp` will now be an array containing the values of your fifth column.